# Proof of absolute convergence and divergence of $ \zeta(s) $

Tags: solution-verification

Is this a valid proof of absolute convergence of $ \zeta(s) $ for $ \Re(s) > 1 $ and divergence of $ \zeta(s) $ for $ \Re(s) < 0 $?

By integral test for convergence, $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left| \frac{1}{n^s} \right| $ converges if and only if $ \int_1^{\infty} \left| \frac{1}{x^s} \right| dx $ converges.

Let $ \sigma = \Re(s) $.

For $ \sigma = 1 $,

$$
\int_1^{\infty} \left| \frac{1}{x^s} \right| dx
= \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} dx
= \left[ \log x \right]_{1}^{\infty}
= \infty.
$$

For $ \sigma \ne 1 $,

$$ \int_1^{\infty} \left| \frac{1}{x^s} \right| dx
= \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{\sigma}} dx
= \frac{1}{(1 - \sigma)} \left[\frac{1}{x^{\sigma - 1}}\right]_{1}^{\infty}
= \begin{cases}
\infty & \text{when} & \sigma < 1, \\
\frac{1}{\sigma - 1} & \text{when} & \sigma > 1.
\end{cases}
$$

This shows that $ \int_1^{\infty} \left| \frac{1}{x^s} \right| dx $ converges for $ \Re(s) > 1 $ and diverges for $ \Re(s) \le 1 $.

Therefore by integral test of convergence $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left| \frac{1}{n^s} \right| $ converges for $ \Re(s) > 1 $ and diverges for $ \Re(s) \le 1 $.

Comment: It proves that it doesn't converge absolutely but not that it diverges at say $s=1+it$

Comment: It doesn't prove that $\sum_n n^{-s}$ diverges

Comment: @reruns That's fine. This question is about the divergence of $ \sum_n \left| n^{-s} \right| $, not that of $ \sum_n n^{-s} $.

Comment: Usually we are interested in the divergence of $\sum_n n^{-s}$ not only of $\sum_n |n^{-s}|$